# generate random darker colors for textview background

Tags: android

I have this to generate colors:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
TexV.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

It works. The problem is that my textview text color is white and when it generates light colors user can barely see its content.

any ideas how to generate only darker colors?

Comment: If you want darker colours, surely you don't want to be using 256 as your upper colour limit? Try halving that number. Also (forgive my lack of knowledge on this, if I'm wrong) but surely you need to change your random seed?

Comment: see `Color#HSVToColor()` method

Answer (score 2):

First off, for true random colors, you should use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the seed. It is always guaranteed to generate a new random sequence.

Secondly, if you want dark colors you should use a lower boundary. Setting them to 255 on every color makes it possible for bright colors to appear as well. if you want dark colors, you have to use a lower limit. I have no clue **how** dark you want the background so I'm not going to supply a number, you have to figure that out yourself. But at least 150 on the limit should generate some dark colors, though if you want really dark colors, 100 or 50 may be better. You need to experiment to find the good limit, and I honestly suggest you use something like Paint.net and mix the color values to see what gives you the darkest colors.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to say, Lunar, but it's a few years since I've used Java...

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler method for this. Use the following code instead

```
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(50), rnd.nextInt(50), rnd.nextInt(50));
```

It generates relatively darker colors.